# generating list of small ascii strings

Tags: java

I want to create a generator class, in java, to produce the next smallest unique ascii string, where the resultant string must begin with an a-Z, and each subsequent letter can be a-Z or 0-9.

The strings are being used to minify variables in a javascript file.

Any suggestions on a tool out there which does this or some rough code as to how you'd implement?

Comment: I assume you want this in Java not Javascript?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a different selection of characters you can use

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    String prev = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 40000000; i++) {
        String s = asId(i);
        if (s.length() > prev.length())
            System.out.print(prev + "\n" + s + " to ");
        prev = s;
    }
}

static char[] CHARS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

public static String asId(long number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long div = number < 52 ? 1 : 52;
    while (div <= number / 62) div *= 62;
    while (div > 0) {
        sb.append(CHARS[((int) (number / div % 62))]);
        div /= 62;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

prints

```
0 to Z
10 to ZZ
100 to ZZZ
1000 to
```

---

You can use the following in Java.

```
public static String asId(long number) {
    return (char) ('a' + number % 26) 
        + (number >= 26 ? Long.toString(number / 26, 36) : "");
}
```

If you concerned about negative numbers you can use.

```
public static String asId(long number) {
    long lowBit = number & 1;
    long highBits = number >>> 1;
    return (char) ('a' + highBits % 13 + lowBit) 
        + (number >= 26 ? Long.toString(highBits / 13, 36) : "");
}
```

Comment: you can. note it is A-Z, a-z as there are characters between Z and a

Comment: Super, thanks.  Right now, 0-25 gives you a-z, then starting on 26 we output 'a1'.  It would be nice if 26 outputted to 'A'.

Comment: @jedierikb I have added code for generating sequences with upper and lower case.

Comment: This is very helpful to see how you implement this.  V much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas (not fully tested!!!)

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    static class VariablesIterator implements Iterator<String>
    {
        private List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

        private List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public VariablesIterator(String start)
        {
            char[] cs = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();

            for (char c : cs)
            {
                characters.add(c);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < start.length(); ++i)
            {
                indices.add(characters.indexOf(start.charAt(i)));
            }
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public String next()
        {
            String current = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i)
            {
                current += characters.get(indices.get(i));
            }

            Integer last = indices.get(indices.size() - 1);

            if (indices.size() != 1 && last != 2*26 + 10 - 1 || indices.size() == 1 && last != 2*26 - 1)
            {
                indices.set(indices.size() - 1, last + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                indices.add(0);
            }

            return current;
        }

        public void remove()
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    static class Variables implements Iterable<String>
    {
        public Iterator<String> iterator()
        {
            return new VariablesIterator("a");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (String variable : new Variables())
        {
            System.out.println(variable);
            in.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```